# How to SELECT multiple columns during a MAX use

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to write a query that gets the greatest amount a person has paid and the date that payment was processed for everyone in my database. My problem is ever time the query runs I get a different date as it's not correlating Max(pmt_amout) to the date of the record. My goal is to be able to run the query for all persons. Here's what I have so far.

```
select person_id, 
MAX(pmt_amount) as greatest_payment, 
pmt_date as greatest_payment_date
from payments p 
group by person_id
```

Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: This is the most frequently asked question under this tag, and it even has its own chapter in the manual. Nevertheless, if you're still struggling see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: Read the manual re group by, you are not using it properly. Google my comments re googling many versions of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem:

**Table Structure** actual Implemented :

Table :

```
CREATE TABLE payments ( 
id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
person_id int(25),
pmt_amount int(25),
pmt_date date,
PRIMARY KEY (id) ) #ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Insert statement :

```
INSERT INTO payments (person_id,pmt_amount,pmt_date)
  VALUES(1,50500,'2017-05-12');
  INSERT INTO payments (person_id,pmt_amount,pmt_date)
  VALUES(1,50500,'2018-05-12');
  INSERT INTO payments (person_id,pmt_amount,pmt_date)
  VALUES(1,10200,'2018-05-12');
  INSERT INTO payments (person_id,pmt_amount,pmt_date)
  VALUES(2,80200,'2018-05-12');
  INSERT INTO payments (person_id,pmt_amount,pmt_date)
  VALUES(3,9300,'2018-06-12');
  INSERT INTO payments (person_id,pmt_amount,pmt_date)
  VALUES(3, 15000,'2018-04-12');
  INSERT INTO payments (person_id,pmt_amount,pmt_date)
  VALUES(4,18000,'2018-03-12');
  INSERT INTO payments (person_id,pmt_amount,pmt_date)
  VALUES(4,15000,'2018-06-12');
```

Query :

```
select person_id, 
MAX(pmt_amount) as greatest_payment, 
pmt_date as greatest_payment_date
from payments p 
group by person_id
ORDER BY pmt_date DESC
```

Ans also visit [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2f66b/3) for your problem

I Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is wrong usage of `group` statement, when selected column is not part of group by expression `ANY` value is selected. As mention by @philipxy please check [Error related to only_full_group_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Try:

```
select p.* 
from payments as p INNER JOIN
(select p2.person_id, MAX(p2.pmt_amount) max_amount from payments p2 group by p2.person_id) sub
on p.person_id = sub.person_id and p.pmt_amount = sub.max_amount
```